# How to check permission for other users in gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

I found a link to documentation which says the ssh info command can be used to look at permissions for other users, but I havent been able to get it to work.

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/info_expand.html

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ ssh git@ahp0625 info git <user>

Usage:  gitolite info [-lc] [-ld] [-json] [<repo name pattern>]

List all existing repos you can access, as well as repo name patterns you can
create repos from (if any).

    '-lc'       lists creators as an additional field at the end.
    '-ld'       lists description as an additional field at the end.
    '-json'     produce JSON output instead of normal output
```

The optional pattern is an unanchored regex that will limit the repos
searched, in both cases.  It might speed up things a little if you have more
than a few thousand repos.

Comment: why g2? gitolite V2. It is obsolete, and g3 has the info command http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#info only for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help message you got, you're using v3, and that too a recent one.

`v3 info` does not allow that syntax.
See [`src/commands/sudo`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4be7ac535c6135b373de70020de4d8874c7990a4/src/commands/sudo) for a more general way to run any command as some other user.
(You need to add '`sudo`', with a trailing comma, in the list of enabled commands in the [`rc` file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#rc) -- [See `Rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4ed15ad8e5d82995b3d55cd17446fc90a3c2b7ec/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L568)).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`ssh git@ahp0625 info git . <user>`

Since it seems that the patern for repos is mandatory, so you can cheat using period, as it says in the link you posted:

> The "info" command shows you all the repos (and repo patterns) in the
>   config file that you have been given any kind of access to. If you
>   supply an optional pattern the output will be limited to repos
>   matching that pattern. If you're an admin you can append a list of
>   users to see their permissions instead of your own; in this mode the
>   pattern is mandatory, even if you just use . to cheat.

Comment: The name pattern in this case is 'git'. Adding a period after it would not be correct. The period can be used as a wildcard and replace the name pattern git. But adding anything after the the name_pattern throws and error.